# Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException: The "node_type" plugin does not exist

Tags: nodes, plugins

I have upgraded drupal 9 to drupal 10 and now while creating a content page or editing the existing content page it is throwing error in error logs

> Drupal\Component\Plugin\Exception\PluginNotFoundException: The
> "node_type" plugin does not exist. Valid plugin IDs for
> Drupal\Core\Condition\ConditionManager are: gtag_domain,
> gtag_language, language, current_theme, request_path, user_role,
> webform, entity_bundle:block_content, entity_bundle:comment,
> entity_bundle:contact_message, entity_bundle:crop,
> entity_bundle:media, entity_bundle:menu_link_content,
> entity_bundle:node, entity_bundle:redirect,
> entity_bundle:taxonomy_term, entity_bundle:vote,
> entity_bundle:webform_submission, entity_bundle:paragraph in
> Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->doGetDefinition() (line 53 of
> /var/www/html/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Component/Plugin/Discovery/DiscoveryTrait.php).

I've also researched a bit and found that node_type is removed from Drupal 10 and instead we write **entity_bundle:node** .

How can I solve this issue as it is coming while creating or editing node?

Answer (score 2):

Search your config files and replace every occurrence of

```
id: node_type
```

With

```
id: entity_bundle:node
```

Import updated config and clear caches, and it should work.

Comment: It looks like pathauto has at least a partial fix (https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto/issues/2925169), though that fix didn't catch all instances. This answer led me to a lingering instance. I'll need to look further into reproducing the issue and will update the d.o thread once I do. It also looks like several other modules took measures also to address their instances of the issue.